# Vue не перезагружает компонент после после изменения какого либо значения в state

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Подскажите, где прочитать информацию или подскажите как решить.
Есть компонент со списком, там например какие-то li выводятся с различными данными. Я кликаю по одному из них, в форме пишу новое имя для li и в vuex в мутациях все обрабатывается и в state передается. Но на странице компонент не перезагружается(Когда удаляю компонент или добовляю, динамика есть)

Comment: Добавьте код, без него сложно что-то вам сказать)

Answer (score 1):

Один из вариантов вызвать в методе Getter, после Action

```
increment(article) {
                this.INCREMENT_CART_ITEM(article)
                    .then(() => {
                        this.VIEW_CART_USER()
                    })
            },
```